# ./configure to use specific compiler

Tags: bash, makefile, g++, configure

My linux environment is based off of a high compute cluster that does not allow users to install to /usr/bin/ or use sudo.  I'm trying to use ./configure (made from protocol buffers) to install to my home.  When configure searches for the CXX files it is not finding the compilers that are located in the bin because they are named things like 'g++34' instead of 'g++'.  I want to point the configure file at this specific compiler, but can't seem to get the command right to do so.  Again the directory where the compiler is gets searched, it is just named funny (using an alias hasn't worked either).

How do you use a arguments in a configure file to point at a specific compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
./configure CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34
```

etc.  If you have a really old version of configure you might have to do it via the environment instead:

```
CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 ./configure
```